# At what angle must one cut the board?

Tags: trigonometry, trigonometric-series, ratio

Given a 2" wide board and a 1 1/2" wide board, we would like to cut the narrower board at an angle $\theta$ so the cut is 2" long so the boards will fit together as shown in the diagram below. At what angle $\theta$ should we cut the board?

[image]

Here's what I have so far. Is this correct?

\begin{gather}
\cos \theta = \frac{\text{adjacent}}{\text{hypotenuse}} \\
1.5 / 2 = 0.75 \\
\cos^{-1}(0.75) = 41.40962211 \text{degrees}
\end{gather}

Comment: Is 2 1/2" a typo? It's 2" in the diagram. Also -- WHY ROBYN? What does the carpenter's name have to do with anything? Excuse my rant -- I know that's just the way things are done these days.

Comment: Yes it's a typo, my bad I'll fix it. Anyways, I know the carpenter's name is irrelevant but that's just how the question was asked on the assignment.

Comment: It's a word problem.  Why *shouldn't* she be named Robyn?  Why we be concerned that she's a carpenter and these are wood?  It'd be the same if she were an automechanic and these were rubber.

Comment: Some edits of language to make things conform... thus making earlier comments refer to some idiosyncrasies which are now gone...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image]

As you can see in the photo above, 1.5" is *actually the opposite side* instead of the adjacent side. Therefore, the answer should be $\arcsin(\frac{1.5}{2}) ≈ 48.59°$.

Comment: That makes sense. Thanks!